# Apple rejected app due to launch crash

Tags: ios, crash, exc-bad-access, segmentation-fault

Apple said that they can't test the app because it crashes on launch. I cannot reproduce the crash and sent me this report crash. How can I know the line where the crashed occurred?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000079706f70
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182ae1b90 0x182ac8000 + 105360
1   MyApp                           0x0000000100064b28 0x100034000 + 199464
2   MyApp                           0x0000000100064a0c 0x100034000 + 199180
3   MyApp                           0x000000010004434c 0x100034000 + 66380
4   UIKit                           0x00000001885c8c40 0x1885b4000 + 85056
5   UIKit                           0x00000001885c8844 0x1885b4000 + 84036
6   UIKit                           0x000000018870daf4 0x1885b4000 + 1415924
7   UIKit                           0x000000018870d8f8 0x1885b4000 + 1415416
8   UIKit                           0x000000018870d730 0x1885b4000 + 1414960
9   UIKit                           0x0000000188710698 0x1885b4000 + 1427096
10  UIKit                           0x00000001885d75b4 0x1885b4000 + 144820
11  UIKit                           0x000000018871246c 0x1885b4000 + 1434732
12  UIKit                           0x0000000188710f70 0x1885b4000 + 1429360
13  UIKit                           0x00000001885e1374 0x1885b4000 + 185204
14  UIKit                           0x00000001885e10e8 0x1885b4000 + 184552
15  UIKit                           0x00000001885d0f14 0x1885b4000 + 118548
16  UIKit                           0x00000001885d013c 0x1885b4000 + 115004
17  UIKit                           0x00000001885cf7e8 0x1885b4000 + 112616
18  UIKit                           0x000000018864149c 0x1885b4000 + 578716
19  MyApp                           0x0000000100050048 0x100034000 + 114760
20  UIKit                           0x000000018863e9c0 0x1885b4000 + 567744
21  UIKit                           0x000000018886e184 0x1885b4000 + 2859396
22  UIKit                           0x00000001888725f0 0x1885b4000 + 2876912
23  UIKit                           0x000000018886f764 0x1885b4000 + 2864996
24  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184e0b7ac 0x184de4000 + 161708
25  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184e0b618 0x184de4000 + 161304
26  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184e0b9c8 0x184de4000 + 162248
27  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018342109c 0x183340000 + 921756
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183420b30 0x183340000 + 920368
29  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018341e830 0x183340000 + 911408
30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183348c50 0x183340000 + 35920
31  UIKit                           0x000000018863794c 0x1885b4000 + 538956
32  UIKit                           0x0000000188632088 0x1885b4000 + 516232
33  MyApp                           0x000000010004820c 0x100034000 + 82444
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182ee68b8 0x182ee4000 + 10424
```

I don't know where to start because in my case the my app is working just fine. I really need a help.

> **UPDATE**:
>   So I tried to Re-Symbolicate log and this is what I got

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182ae1b90 objc_msgSend + 16
1   MyApp                           0x0000000100064b28 -[DBManager copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory] (DBManager.m:56)
2   MyApp                           0x0000000100064a0c -[DBManager initWithDatabaseFilename:] (DBManager.m:43)
3   MyApp                           0x000000010004434c -[DoorTalkViewController viewDidLoad] (DoorTalkViewController.mm:133)
4   UIKit                           0x00000001885c8c40 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
5   UIKit                           0x00000001885c8844 -[UIViewController view] + 28
6   UIKit                           0x000000018870daf4 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 488
7   UIKit                           0x000000018870d8f8 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 68
8   UIKit                           0x000000018870d730 -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 404
9   UIKit                           0x0000000188710698 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 252
10  UIKit                           0x00000001885d75b4 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 80
11  UIKit                           0x000000018871246c -[UITabBarController _selectDefaultViewControllerIfNecessaryWithAppearanceTransitions:] + 332
12  UIKit                           0x0000000188710f70 -[UITabBarController viewWillAppear:] + 200
13  UIKit                           0x00000001885e1374 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 628
14  UIKit                           0x00000001885e10e8 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 156
15  UIKit                           0x00000001885d0f14 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 596
16  UIKit                           0x00000001885d013c -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 444
17  UIKit                           0x00000001885cf7e8 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 664
18  UIKit                           0x000000018864149c -[UIWindow setRootViewController:] + 1076
19  MyApp                           0x0000000100050048 -[idoubs2AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (idoubs2AppDelegate.mm:374)
20  UIKit                           0x000000018863e9c0 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 400
21  UIKit                           0x000000018886e184 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2904
22  UIKit                           0x00000001888725f0 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1684
23  UIKit                           0x000000018886f764 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
24  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184e0b7ac __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
25  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184e0b618 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 168
26  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000184e0b9c8 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
27  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018342109c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
28  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183420b30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
29  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018341e830 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
30  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183348c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
31  UIKit                           0x000000018863794c -[UIApplication _run] + 460
32  UIKit                           0x0000000188632088 UIApplicationMain + 204
33  MyApp                           0x000000010004820c main (main.m:25)
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000182ee68b8 start + 4
```

> **UPDATE:** 
>   CopyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory method that I got from tutorial

```
-(void)copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory{
    // Check if the database file exists in the documents directory.
    NSString *destinationPath = [self.documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:destinationPath]) {
        // The database file does not exist in the documents directory, so copy it from the main bundle now.
        NSString *sourcePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:self.databaseFilename];
        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:&error];

        // Check if any error occurred during copying and display it.
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]); 
        }
    }
}
```

Line 56 is `NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);`

Comment: Start by symbolicating the crash log so you can see where in your app it is crashing.

Comment: @rmaddy Is my symbolicating right? This is my first time doing this so it's all new to me, sorry.

Comment: Did you ensure the directory you're copying into exists first?

Comment: That looks better. Now update your question with your `DBManager copyDatabaseIntoDocumentsDirectory` method and point out line 56.

Comment: check how you handle your local data storage. And please double check the whole new and upgrade case. The reason why Apple crash but you cannot reproduce it is because you are in different case, ex not try remove and re-install or not try update app from previous version

Comment: Just log `error`. BTW - you should not check if `error` is `nil` or not. Check the return value of `copyItemAtPath`. If it fails, then log `error`. And test your app as a clean install. Delete your app from your device and do a clean build to your device. Then test the app.

Comment: @rmaddy I followed your instructions on deleting and clean install. Here is the return of copyItemAtPath: 

`copyItemPath: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/6B183AFD-9760-4F2B-9F73-FF1A4772D9D4/MyApp.app/Database.db`

This is really strange because on the previous version this part has no problem. I just made a minor update on the app and all of a sudden it's not working on apple's side when I submitted it for review.

Comment: I had same problem before, app was crashing only with Apple review team. It's ended up that they were testing the iPhone app on iPad. I have some logic that was crashing only in iPad and since it's iPhone app I have never tested it on iPad.

Comment: @HossamGhareeb That's what I'm thinking right now, maybe I should right an appeal to them? And say that In my case there is really no problem at all.

Comment: Try to check first the crash report if you can get device/OS information. Try different scenarios like first installation

Comment: @HossamGhareeb I just checked, it says iphone. I already did hard installation and everything but I don't get the crash. The problem in apple's side is that it cannot copy the database to the main bundle and I don't know why. I tried to modify the permission of my database file (.db) and try to submit it again to apple and hope that it will be accepted for the 3rd time.

Comment: @JaysonOng you *should* test on iPad, since iPhone apps must run on an iPad at iPhone 4 resolution.

Comment: @rmaddy it finally got accepted! The only changes I made were removing the condition to check if error is nil or not and Hossam Ghareeb's answer though it may not be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check something, please update the initialization of the error to:

```
NSError *error = nil;
```

I doubt that actually there is no error but it's pointed to some address with garbage data. So the condition `error != nil` will return `true` but will not able recognize the selector `localizedDescription`.

Comment: I doubt that this is the issue.  Objects are initialised to `nil` implicitly in Objective-C.  The OP hasn't included the text of the exception but I suspect it may be unrecognized selector since the error occurred in `objc_msgSend`; probably the object that was returned doesn't have a `localizedDescription` value.  The OP needs to find out *why* an error was returned and diagnose the underlying problem

Comment: It may not be this issue but when I submitted it again to the appstore it finally got accepted. The only changes I made were this one and rmaddy's suggestion.